# Understanding phrases

Tags: phrases

> The girl running in the wood is my sister.

In the above sentence,
1. The girl running in the wood
2. Running in the wood
3. In the wood

What types of phrases are these?

Answer (score 2):

1. *The girl running in the wood* is a **noun phrase** headed by the noun *girl*, which has *the* as a determiner and *running in the wood* as a modifier.
2. *Running in the wood* is a **participle phrase** (in some grammatical sects a gerund-participle phrase *or* clause) headed by the present participle (in some grammatical sects the gerund-participle), which is modified by *in the wood*.
3. *In the wood* is a **preposition phrase** headed by the preposition *in* with the noun phrase *the girl* as its object (in some grammatical sects its oblique).